# Design advice for Zend application

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework-mvc

Looking for some advice \ improvements on the structure of my application

user logs in and is presented with a welcome message and a menu of options
each option points to the same controller e.g OptionController but with different actions

/option/abc 
/option/def

```
OptionController.php
{
abcAction()
defAction()
}
```

the reason why I have different actions is because each option will require a different form

when the form is rendered and the user enters input the request is submitted to a validate controller again with a different action per option. i need basic form validation + custom business logic

I have it "working" but don't think it's a good way to do it. Thoughts?

Comment: Are you asking if only having one controller with a lot of actions is bad?

Comment: No. It's more with the handling of the form. Should I have an action to render the form + an action to process the form in the same controller? If the validation fails I'd like to redisplay the form with appropriate validate error

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a structure where you summarize not the art (display, validated) of task, but the, in your words, "options"

for example (:

```
controller: abcController
actions:    addAction()
            editAction()
            listAction()
            viewAction()
            deleteAction()


controller: defController
actions:    addAction()
            editAction()
            listAction()
            viewAction()
            deleteAction()
```

the configs for your forms (including validation) should be in own classes extended from Zend_Form which are stored in its own folder. eg APPLICATION_PATH.'/forms'. (see ZF - autoloader) displaying and validating forms can reside in the same action, i usaly split them into add and edit. (but using the same form class for both)

task's you need in all controllers are best to be implemented as action or view helpers.

Comment: maybe it would be better to split each option into its own controller. thanks